# Is there a service which allows me to shift where an IP address actually resolves to?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

What I mean is, I have my clients point their A-Records to an IP address of mine for hosting purposes. Then, when I decide to move data centers, I have to make all of them point their A-Records to a new IP address. I would like to mitigate the risk of this happening by having them point their A-Records to an IP address `A` that some how routes to whatever IP address `B` that I want to, so I can easily fail over from one data center to another, or change data centers for whatever reason. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just have them point their A Records to an A record you control. It'd actually have to be something like a cname record, then you can just change your a record and they wont have to do anything.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek - can you explain what you mean by an "A record you control".

Comment: Basically what becoming wisest is describing to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few options.

- Have them use CNAMES instead, so you control the final A record lookup.
- Manage DNS for them or have access to their DNS management portal, so you can make such changes.
- Unlikely, but get your own IP block, so when you migrate to DC B, you can move your entire range there.
- If its just websites, perhaps leave a reverse proxy at DC A, that knows to look for the stuff at DC B.

Comment: They will be using CNAMEs for `www`, but that doesn't help me with root requests to their domains (e.g. `http://example.com`), or does it?

Comment: No, you need an A record for the naked domain name, e.g., example.com. Some DNS providers have a concept of DNS forwarding for naked domain names (i.e., in their control panel you say foo.com forwards to bar.com, and they will poll the A record for bar.com, and present that IP as the A record for foo.com), so you get some redirection, but it may not help in your case.